# windows server which files are in cache

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cache

Is there a way to see which files are cached in a windows server 2008R2?

I'd like to see/analyse which files are being used most to make choices how to optimize data on a server and for this it would help to see wich files are being cached most or use most cache memory.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the filesystem cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Sysinternals RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

The following link gives this example:

> If you want to check for performance regression tests if your cache is
> filled you could execute
>
> rammap C:\temp\ram.xml
>
> to get a nice xml file which shows which files are being in the cach
> now. The cached files are stored as xml nodes of the form
>
> File Key="3114984784" Path="C:\windows\system32\aelupsvc.dll"

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190907094826/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/archive/2013/11/14/154624.aspx)